# Use default key for encrypting SNS topic

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Creating a new SNS Topic:

```
const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'Topic', {
    masterKey: USE_DEFAULT
});
```

I would like to use the KMS key managed by AWS to encrypt my topic. How ver I do not want to import it using lookups during synth time.

How would this be done?

Comment: Which key do you want to use, though?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code snippet to use the AWS managed KMS keys.

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_kms.Alias.html#static-fromwbraliaswbrnamescope-id-aliasname

```
import * as kms from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-kms"
import * as sns from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns"

const aws_sns_kms = kms.Alias.fromAliasName(
      your_stack,
      "aws-managed-sns-kms-key",
      "alias/aws/sns",
    )

    // Create new SNS topic
    const snsTopic = new sns.Topic(
        stack,
      “Test-sns-topic”,
      { masterKey: aws_sns_kms },
    )
```